# no errors are thrown but nothing changes in the database

Tags: php, mysql

It works on my localhost but not on the server. Does this mean the database is not connecting at all or do I have something wrong in the statements?

```
$submission = $_POST['submit'];
$decode = json_decode($submission, true);

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:localhost;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'PDO Exception: '.$e->getMessage();
    die();
}

class QueryBuilder {
    protected $pdo;
    public function __construct($pdo){
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function insert($parameters){
        $sql = "insert into tableName ('entry', 'author', 'email', 'sign', 'month') values (:entry, :author, :email, :sign, :month)";
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        try {
            $statement->execute($parameters);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

$query = new QueryBuilder($pdo);
$query->insert($decode);
```

I even tried a table clearing statement and it also does nothing...

```
public function clear(){
    try {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("truncate table submissions");
        $statement->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

$query->clear();
```

Comment: Are you sure "$decode" holds all the parameters you need?

Comment: You turned error reporting on? `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
`

Comment: try localhost name to server name

Comment: look for errors inside the php.log

Comment: When referencing column names `('entry',` use backticks `(\`entry\`,`

Comment: Hm tried all that, but it's still not working :/ Switched localhost to server name, used backticks, and checked $decode again and it holds all the parameters, but  still nothing changes.

I also turned error reporting on but no errors show or an error.log file on the server. I'm so confused

Comment: What is the return value of `$statement->execute($parameters);` ? Should be true if everything went okay, false otherwise.

Comment: how do I check the value for it? echo $statement->execute($parameters) ?

Comment: ok I checked it with an if else statement and looks $statement->execute($parameters); is false. Does this mean the database is connecting fine, but there is something wrong with the prepare command?

Comment: See also http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php  -- You should set your PDO attributes for error handing: `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`  See the comments section on how to set this: `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: [`$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Thanks guys. I set up pdo error handling and now it says
SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

So I guess it's not accessing the database at all. It's so weird though. I checked again. The database is created with all privileges granted and all the credentials I entered look correct